# *** AttributeError: model object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I have a Python Django models.py like below-

```
class Nx2FwComponent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

 class Nx2FwComponentWithPath(models.Model):
    nx2FwComponent = models.ForeignKey(Nx2FwComponent)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.path + '/' + str(self.nx2fwComponent))
```

The database tables are populated as shown -

```
sqlite> select * from config_nx2fwcomponent;
1|mfw
2|mba
3|feb
4|ib_ipv4n6
sqlite> select * from config_nx2fwcomponentwithpath;
1|V:\rels\mba|2
```

In my views.py, when I run -

```
Nx2FwComponentWithPath.objects.all()
```

I get this error-

```
(Pdb) Nx2FwComponentWithPath.objects.all()
*** AttributeError: 'Nx2FwComponentWithPath' object has no attribute 'nx2fwComponent'
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: self.nx2fwComponent to self.nx2FwComponent (fw->FW)?

Comment: At first sight, what appears to be wrong is that the model field is called `nx2FwComponent` and not `ns2fwComponent`.

Comment: Exactly, that was it! Really dumb of me to give same names. Thanks a lot people.